# Visual Studio editor losing focus when unit testing

Tags: visual-studio, unit-testing, focus, resharper

This may be a trivial question but I had no luck finding an answer so I ended up asking by myself.(I apologize if there already is a same question...)

I'm using VS2012 + Resharper + TestAfterBuild plugin. I've set the TestAfterBuild setting to **ReSharper.ReSharper_UnitTest_RunSolution** and every time I build the solution, the unit test runs. This is really nice and if I use ".NET Demon" with these it's supposed to become even nicer.

But the problem is, every time I build and the unit test runs, VS2012's focus moves to the "Unit Test Sessions" window. This gets annoying especially when you use the ".NET Demon" because every time you type something, it builds > unit tests > editor loses focus.

This behavior is supposed to be avoidable hence the movie [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t7X_-eKDhwk) isn't losing focus.

Can someone lead me to a solution?
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I don't know if this is the right answer but I happened to accidentally find a solution by myself.
I was getting the "Build Failed" error mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6061070/unit-tests-are-failing-on-a-build-failed-in-the-session-window-with-no-message) and turned the Resharper build setting to 'never build'.
That solved my "Build Failed" error but another thing I noticed was that my focus didn't move to the "Unit Test Sessions" window.
Then I turned ".NET Demon"'s "Save Continuously" option ON to see if the focus stays on the code editor. And it did!
As I said above, I don't know if this is the right solution but so far I think it's working nice for me.
But still, I'd love to hear any other solutions I can try.
Thanks again.